# Python: TypeError __init__() takes exactly 5 arguments (4 given)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, typeerror

I just started to work with Python and came across a problem I have no explanation for. Hope you can help out.

```
def createGrid(x,y,N):
    nDictionary={}
    for i in range(N+1):
        node=Node(i,x/N*i,y/N*i)
        nDictionary[node.nlabel] = node 

    return nDictionary

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self,nlabel,x,y,z):
        self.nlabel = nlabel
        self.coordinates = x,y,z
```

Now

```
nDictionary={}
node=Node(0,0,0,0)
nDictionary[node.nlabel]=node
```

works but calling the method

```
createGrid(10,10,10)
```

leads to the following error

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 5 arguments (4 given)
```

I really don't know why.

Comment: when calling `createGrid(10,10,10)` you are supplying only 3 arguments.
Class Node object takes 5 arguments out of which `self` is implicitly provided and rest four arguments are supplied explicitly

Comment: You are forgetting to give the `nlabel` to the Node instance you create by calling `createGrid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is with this line:

```
node=Node(i,x/N*i,y/N*i)
```

I'd guess you would like to have 4 arguments here, not 3.

(The reason the error message is slightly confusing (saying you should have 5, 4 given) is because of special handling of the `self` parameter - see [an external explanation](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/))

Comment: yeah he is not providing the label for some reason. Must have forgotten.

Comment: actually my vertices are two-dimensional, so I have to pass an extra zero as z-coordinate to make the code work.